# How to set a claim in a Firebase User using Angular Fire Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I was reading about Angular Fire Auth guards and I found this function "hasCustomClaim(claim)". What I want to know is how can I set a "claim" for a user in my app in Angular.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Based on what I read I think I have to do this in the backend using node.js or another.  But I didn't create a backend service, so, it is possible to set a "claim" in the FrontEnd using Angular ? or this is insecure in any way ?. If the only way to do this is using the backend, I want to know if It is possible to upload a folder with my frontend code and another folder with my backend code in the same hosting in AWS.

I am new to hosting applications. I hope you can help me.

The main thing that I want to do is avoid a user entry to a route that is only for admins. That's why I read about the "hasCustomClaim(claim)" function in Angular Fire Auth guards. I think this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing a user to set a custom claim in the front-end application would be quite insecure, as it'd mean that any user can make any claim they want about themselves. So to do this securely, the claims will really need to be set from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

A simple way to get started with the latter would be to use the experimental [Set Auth claims with Firestore](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims), that you can then trigger by writing to Firestore from your Angular app. Note that you will have to [write security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) for Cloud Firestore that ensure only authorized users can request claims this way, otherwise you still end up with the same security risk I mentioned at the start.